# What does an object descontruction means in this context

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to understand what does this piece of code means in `vuesax` VueJS framework (https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuesax-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/documentation/components/table.html#default)

```
<vs-table stripe :data="users">
          <template slot-scope="{data}">
            <vs-tr :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" >
              <vs-td :data="data[indextr].email">
                {{data[indextr].email}}
              </vs-td>

              <vs-td :data="data[indextr].username">
                {{data[indextr].name}}
              </vs-td>

              <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                {{data[indextr].website}}
              </vs-td>

              <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                {{data[indextr].id}}
              </vs-td>
            </vs-tr>
          </template>
        </vs-table>
...
data() {
  users:[
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "owner": "Bruno Francisco",
                        "token": "123XCS456ECS65ED",
                        "description": "To be used in production server",
                        "last_refreshed": "",
                        "created_at": "hildegard.org",
                    }, 
    ], ...
}
```

I'm more interested in the `slot-scope="{data}"`. What does it do exactly? This to me looks like an object deconstruction but I'm not sure how to understand this. Is this referencing the `:data` prop in the `<vs-table stripe :data="users">` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a destructured [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

Explanation:

They are exposing a way for you to access the `data` variable that is internally used in that component (technically it's `datax` in the component).

The reason it is being destructured is because they could expose multiple variables or functions through that scoped slot.  For instance they could do something like this:

```
<template slot-scope="slotProps">
  <button @click="slotProps.someFunction()">{{ slotProps.someLabel }}</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="d in slotProps.data"></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

But in this case they're just exposing and using the `data` variable.